# An Embedded Collection in an Entity Only Renders up to 10 Entities in Apigility

Tags: rest, laminas-api-tools

I have created a resource that when fetched `GET /resource/{id}` returns a response (on success/found) with the following template:

### Resource:

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "code" "Code",
    "_embedded" : {
        "foos" : [{
            "name" : "bar1",
            "value" : "value1",
       },
       {
            "name" : "bar2",
            "value" : "value2",
       }]
    }

}
```

### Code for fetch($id)

```
fetch($id){

    $resource = ... // query resource

    $resourceEntity = new ResourceEntity();
    $resourceEntity->exchangeArray($resource);

    $foos = ... // query foos
    $fooAdapter = new Adapter\ArrayAdapter($foos);
    $fooCollection = new Foo\FooCollection($fooAdapter);

    $resourceEntity->foos = $fooCollection;

    return $resourceEntity;

}
```

My problem is that when the fooCollection consists of **more** than 10 entities **only** 10 entities gets rendered in response.

#### Things I tried so far:

- I checked if this has to do with the `default page size` of the `FooCollection` in the `module.config.php` but the setting is equal to 25 in my case.
- I tried to look at the Zend documentation to see if I can force the `Paginator` to be set to -1, since by doing so (I think) will not paginate the result.
- I tried not used a Collection to just a plain array for the `"foos"` property. I showed all the results but it did not render each `foo` entities as a `HAL` entity

Answer (score 1):

Finally!

The `Collection`s in Apigility extends from `Zend\Paginator\Paginator`. As per the [docs](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.paginator.configuration.html#zend-paginator-configuration), the default page size (or item count per page) of a paginator is 10.

All I have to do is to set the page size to `-1` using `$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(-1)` to tell the paginator to include all entities in a single page.